# Exporting chrome output to python

Tags: javascript, python

I'm looking for a way get a console output from Google Chrome into my `python` program. I have a script coded in `JS` that finishes in around 1 second, but my `python` implementation (exactly same logic, etc., the only difference is that it's in `python` and not `JS`) takes about 15 seconds to run. Therefore I'm looking for a way to get the printout in Chrome console to my `python` program.

This is the current way I'm doing it:

`Python` program uses `pyautogui` to click and does what it needs to do inside to trigger the function running in `JS`.

`JS` completes the function in 1s and prints to console, something like:

```
(22) [6, 4, 4, 6, 0, 1, 1 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 0]
```

I would like to find a way to get this output into `python` as I have another script that takes the output and does further calculations to it.

I've thought of using `Selenium` but that'd introduce too much overhead (probably requiring 3s+ for waiting for chrome to open up).

Comment: Why not run the `py` script in the console and output it there?

Comment: Obviously your code in Python itself seems like the issue. 1s vs 15s. Because running javascript in chrome, capture the output and then process it will definitely cause overhead + delay.

Comment: Show us the Python code so we can see if it can be improved. How you are going about this seems very backwards.

Comment: It sounds like there might be issues in your python code that make it run so slow. In order for us to help you with it, you will need to show it. See [mcve] for some tips about how to create a good code example.

Comment: The code is basically https://github.com/chocolatemelt/padopt but in python (only the optimizer part)

Comment: Using PyAutoGUI might be overkill for this and is probably brittle. If you need to get your JS results to Python, you can try setting up your JS code so that it makes an http request to localhost, sending the info to a web server you run on your machine. The web server can be a simple Flask app running on Python. This means you might have to learn a few new things, but it would be much more robust than using PyAutoGUI to copy/paste results. However, I'd recommend that you figure out why your Python code is running so much slower.